# Butchering meat from mutant giant rats and lizards?

Tags: internal-consistency, food

So, in my world, there was a nuclear apocalypse, which resulted in two new species of animals, radrats (capybara sized brown rats) and geckos (3ft. tall leopard geckos) emerging.

About a generation after the apocalypse, a woman finds an old cookbook that isn’t missing too many pages out of it, and decides she wants to use some of the recipes. Unfortunately, she is limited in ingredients, but she does have radrats and geckos handing around. So, she decides to use them as the basis of her culinary career, and later passes down the recipes she creates.

Here’s my question: what would the best quality/most nutritious cuts of meat from the rats and geckos?

***Bonus*** How pleasing to the palate would they be and why? And what types of dishes would they serve well in?

Also the Geckos aren’t toxic

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you'll get hard answers, because a large animal will have different qualities than a small one.  Diet will greatly affect the quality of the meat as well. Predators might be gamey. You'll be safe making stuff up to fit the story because there are enough variables to justify any assumptions you please. Rats taste like chicken to rabbit (dark meat is gamey); geckos and other lizards taste like chicken.https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/2019/03/vietnam-rats-eating-food-cuisine/ https://www.quora.com/What-do-reptiles-taste-like-when-eaten-cooked

Answer (score 2):

If you want to base your giant rat meat similar to that of smaller rats, according to articles, the feet and tails are expecially good. You need to cook rats at high temperatures to kill off pathogens, or it could cause infections. This sight lists several ways rats are eaten in native cultures that you could go off of. [Site link.](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20151207-the-countries-where-rats-are-on-the-menu#:%7E:text=The%20rat%27s%20tail%20and%20feet,rats%20as%20a%20food%20resource.) You say they are Capybara sized, and that might affect the way they taste or are prepared. Luckily for us, Capybaras are eaten in certain cultures as well. According to the internet, They don’t taste like chicken – they taste like pork. Capybara are native to South America, where the meat is considered a delicacy and is served Salt-cured. They are often just cooked over a spit or in a stew. If you need more specifics, there are videos on Youtube I am too squeamish to watch.

As for the gecko, eating any reptile carries risks because they carry diseases people aren't accustomed to, but they are still eaten in areas, and can be eaten raw, though I don't suggest it. Reptile eggs are a far more common delicacy, so some of your recipes could involve the eggs. Look [here](http://prepare-and-protect.net/2015/10/edible-reptiles/) for more information in preparing various reptiles. Lizard meat is flakey, but larger lizards like the Komodo are more gamey in flavour. Crocodile is relatively easy to cook and eat, and is served similar to steak, so I assume the red meat of your Gecko wouldn't be much different preparation-wise to a cow or crocodile. Also if you are refering to the house Gecko, the skin and mouth area are not safe to eat, so they might be served skinned or fillet.

I hope this helps.